# What should I put in Cloud Scheduler Payload in order to reset scores in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I have an iOS/swift game with a leaderboard, and I'd like the scores to all reset to 0 every Monday at 12:00am.

I believe I'm all set up (enabled the Blaze plan, followed the steps in the [Getting Started with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYfP-UIKxH0) and also the [Cloud Scheduler Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart), etc), but I'm a bit unclear on how it all connects and both feel so distant from my database.

How can I get this Google Cloud Scheduler job to reset the scores for all users in my Firebase Realtime Database when it runs? I'm guessing I put some code in the Payload field?

[image: Cloud Scheduler]

Apologies if my question isn't precisely worded or is missing needed information. It feels like just a few months ago that I dipped my toes into programming and wrote print("Hello World") in Xcode and now here we are :D

Thanks in advance for any direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the documentation for [scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).  If you're deploying with the Firebase CLI, everything will get set up for you automatically on the schedule you specify in the function.  You don't even have to go to the Cloud console at all to configure Cloud Scheduler.  Just write your function to do what you want, whenever it gets invoked by the scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So, if I'm understanding this correctly, I would write my code "export scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule(‘0 0 * * 1’).onRun((context) => {console.log(‘The code that I will write here will run every Monday at 12:00 AM UTC’);
});" in the index.ts file in VS Code that's connected to my app, then run "firebase deploy" in terminal and it's all set. Is that correct?

Comment: Along with the code that does what you want to do with your database.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Woah! I just realized I am talking to the same celebrity Doug Stevenson as was in the video. :D

Comment: I'm not a celebrity - I just play one on TV.